# Is KF the most ionic compound?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, ionic-compounds, electronegativity

I saw somewhere (can't recall where) that KF is the most ionic compound.  I expected CsF.  Does the greater polarizability of Cs allow it to more easily form covalent bonds compared to K?  Does this overcome the fact that K being in n = 4 should bond better with F in n = 2?

Comment: use hannay- smith equation and fajan rule togther,you will get your answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, this is a subtle thing.

Using the [Pauling electronegativities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity), one would expect CsF to have the larger electronegativity difference (3.2). So in principal, it should be "more ionic."

Unfortunately, an ionic bond requires separating charge, so $\ce{Cs+F-}$. The problem is that $\ce{Cs+}$ is much larger than $\ce{K+}$ and so the dipole moment for a fully ionic $\ce{Cs+F-}$ would be much larger.

We find that the charge isn't fully separated, likely because of the need to stabilize the large dipole moment.

So some people plot a curve of "% ionic character" as determined by the ***actual*** dipole moment vs. the expected dipole moment (i.e, full charge separation). We find that this curve reaches a limit ~75-85% ionic character.

IIRC, I think on that basis LiF is more Ionic than KF.

[image]

For more, I really like Bruce Robinson's lecture notes:
[http://courses.washington.edu/bhrchem/c152/Lec23.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20160406074454/http://courses.washington.edu/bhrchem/c152/Lec23.pdf) via [the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160406074454/http://courses.washington.edu/bhrchem/c152/Lec23.pdf)

Comment: The bit about having to separate the dipole moment was very helpful.

Comment: I could go to [hard-soft acid base theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSAB_theory) since $\ce{Cs}$ is a softer cation than $\ce{K+}$ or $\ce{Li+}$ but I think the dipole moment is sufficient to explain the trend.

Comment: I always used HSAB theory to rationalize it but wanted more so I came here.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison This answer is quite good. May I add something that the OP might find useful:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fajans%27_rules
Cheers!