# Covalent and Ionic bonds with Semi-metals

Tags: covalent-compounds

why are some semimetals considered as a metal, and some, a nonmetal when paired with some atoms. 
Like in BF, it is an ionic bond, but in SiCl, it is a covalent bond. 
Do their electronegativities matter?

Comment: I would never call a $\ce{B-F}$ bond ionic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact difference in electronegativity is the defining property.  Ionic character of a bond is given by: 
$$ \mathrm{\% IC = 1-exp[-\frac{1}{4}(\chi_A - \chi_B)^2]}$$
Where $\chi_A$ and $\chi_B$ are the electronegativities of the anion and cation species.  When $|\chi_A - \chi_B|$ exceeds 1.665 the ionic character transitions from less than $50\%$ ionic to more than $50\%$ ionic, making the compound ionic.

Comment: oh so, if i subtract the electronegativity of a, for example, a semimetal and a nonmetal, and if it is greater than 1, will the semimetal become a metal?

Comment: No, not at all.  Electronegativity is only informative about the ionic nature of the bond.

Comment: It's only a suggestion about nature of bonding http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/17064/why-is-kf-the-most-ionic-compound