# Which has more ionic character, LiF or K2O?

Tags: bond, ionic-compounds, dipole

After drawing the structures of both and considering dipole moment, doesn't it seems that all K2O should have more ionic character than LiF?
My textbook says its LiF.

Comment: Li and F are very small atoms hence they form strong covalent bond.

Comment: So why they have more ionic character?

Comment: I do not know the answer, looks like I did not frame my comment properly. It appears more like an answer.

Comment: I don't think one can compare the ionic character of compounds where both the anion and cation are different. I have no idea on what basis one would decide which is more ionic.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/17064/why-is-kf-the-most-ionic-compound