# I have a question regarding chemical bonds

Tags: bond

can NaCl bond be called polar covalent bond? I understand that it's ionic bond
but Na is still sharing its electron with Cl. I am confused with Ionic and polar covalent bond.

Comment: There should be *some* duplicate around here somewhere that explains how to call a bond (if ionic or polar covalent is more acceptable). Unfortunately, I'm too lazy to look for it now.

Answer (score 0):

The sodium and chlorine ions do not actually share their electrons. Instead, chlorine "takes" an electron from sodium. They are kept together in a crystal lattice by electrostatic interactions between the net +1 charge of Na and net -1 charge of Cl, thusly making the bond ionic. If they were truly sharing their electrons, then yes, it would be considered polar covalent. But if that also were true, then dissolving NaCl in water would be much more difficult as the sodium and chloride cannot be separated.

An example of a polar covalent bond will be between carbon and oxygen, say carbon monoxide CO. These two atoms actually share their electrons and make it more difficult to separate the two atoms.

Comment: You're wrong and OP's right... All "ionic" bonds are partially covalent.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/17064/why-is-kf-the-most-ionic-compound/17072?s=3|0.2164#17072

Comment: @Mithron As this is the OP's first post, and because they are having difficulty differentiating b/w covalent and non-covalent, I assumed they are a student of general chemistry. It is best not to confuse these students with % ionic character so early in their education. But yes, you are right in that there exists partial covalency.

Comment: Well, denying what he already knows would be rather more confusing... Edit your post.